# What exactly does the "Indicates the start of a managed heap garbage collection" mean, and is it bad?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, garbage-collection

What exactly does

> Indicates the start of a managed heap garbage collection

mean, and is it bad?

While running the visual studio debugger I am looking at the process memory and when one of my operations takes place there are a number of those yellow symbols in the process memory graph indicating that a number of "Indicates the start of a managed heap garbage collection" operations have occurred. The code processes in a reasonable time, so is this a bad thing?

Comment: It means that the garbage collection is starting to clean up your heap. Probably because it needs new memory blocks that are no longer available without removing the garbage. This itself is neither bad nor good (well, rather _good_ because otherwise your app would crash with an `OutOfMemoryException`). It _may indicate_ that you could organize your code better to avoid heavy memory consumption and fragmentation, but we can't tell without knowing what your code is doing and _how_ it is doing that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What does "Indicates the start of a managed heap garbage collection" mean?

The CLR has a garbage collector. It tracks how much memory is being used, and when its heuristics indicate that now might be a good time to try to reclaim unused memory, it collects the garbage memory and releases it.  In doing so it compacts the heap.

> is it bad?

There are a variety of different garbage collection strategies depending on what version of the CLR you are using and how it is configured. Some of them are "stop the world" collectors; that is, your program is paused for a few milliseconds while the collection happens.  **If your program requires realtime or near realtime processing of events with a time budget of less than a few milliseconds, then a collection at the wrong time can be really bad**.

For example, suppose you are writing code to analyze the flight path of an incoming missile moving at several thousand meters per second, and trigger some countermeasures. If you get it wrong by a couple milliseconds because there was a garbage collection at the wrong time, your analysis could be off by several meters, and you could miss your target.  **Do not write software to run missile intercept systems in C#**.  People could die.  That's really bad.

For example, suppose you are writing a game which refreshes the screen 60 times a second.  That gives you less than 17 milliseconds per refresh to do all the game computations necessary. If doing so takes 14 milliseconds, then **a garbage collection could cause you to miss a frame**.  Gamers could be irritated.  That's really bad.

For example, suppose you are writing line-of-business software that updates a database and it takes ten seconds to update the database. A garbage collection could interrupt that and it could then take ten seconds plus three milliseconds.  That's not bad. That's fine.

**Analyze your application from a user-experience performance standpoint, set a performance budget, and verify that the garbage collections cause you to stay within your budget**.  If you are not in budget with garbage collections then you need to use special techniques to control how and when collections are performed to ensure that they happen at a moment that is in-budget.

In particular, **if you are out of your performance budget for collections then you must manage collection pressure**. "Pressure" is the heuristic that the GC uses to decide when to collect; it is a combination of how much memory has been allocated recently, the size of the allocations, how many collections the memory survived, and many other factors.

When we were designing Roslyn -- the current generation of C# compiler technology -- we had to very careful to manage collection pressure because the compiler makes many, many small allocations in-between keystrokes in the editor.  There were scenarios in which we were not getting analysis fast enough to produce IntelliSense behaviours during typing due to unwanted collections. We used a variety of techniques to reduce both pressure, and the amount of work the collector had to do to move memory during a collection.

**These are advanced techniques**.  If you are in your budget, don't worry about them.  But you will not know if you are in your budget until you make a budget, and measure whether you're in it!

Comment: right now the operation takes about 1.7 seconds with a fairly large number of garbage collections. That time length is fine for my purpose. Theoretically though if I wanted to reduce the number of garbage collections how would I go about that?

Comment: @user9964422: There are a great many ways to reduce the number of collections. Some techniques I would try and **do empirical research on** would be (1) make fewer allocations, (2) have more virtual memory available, (3) have more physical memory available, (4) allocate non-collected memory and manage it yourself, (5) use pooling and object resurrection to move objects into the gen2 heap, which is collected less often, (6) allocate out of the large object pool, which is collected less often, ...  and so on. **You must become an expert on the GC if you wish to pursue this route**.

Comment: @user9964422: But the question is not the question to ask in the first place.  More frequent collections that take less time each is often better than infrequent expensive collections!  You need to make sure that you are budgeting appropriately for your realistic user scenario.  Will a user care if the program is 0.1% slower overall?  Will the user care if the program is 0% slower *most* of the time but *sometimes* a normally-1ms operation takes 10ms? These are the sorts of questions you must consider when optimizing the collector.

Comment: @user9964422: Right now you do not know even the basics to begin to do such work, so learn that first.  Rico's article from 2003 is still pretty accurate as to the basics: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 A more recent article that describes the concurrent collector that does not stop the world is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals

Comment: Okay thank you for your help. As you can probably tell I am rather new to coding.

Comment: @user9964422: The garbage collector was carefully designed so that **for the vast majority of realistic applications you do not need to worry about it**.  That's the whole *point* of GC languages, is that they free you from having to deal with this tedious, error-prone aspect of programming.  If you are designing an application that has serious real-world performance needs where a few milliseconds spent in the wrong place can mean the difference between success and failure, then you need to worry about the GC.  Otherwise, let it do its job; it's there for your convenience.

Comment: @user9964422: For example, you are probably not writing an application that analyzes changes to a hundred-thousand line C# program *in the time between keystrokes*.  Do you use an editor with IntelliSense? If so, then you are using a program that solves this problem. We had to worry about many aspects of the collector, and many other unrelated performance problems, to make that work.  If you need to solve such problems, enlist the services of an expert.

Comment: @user9964422: It is by no means clear that you are new to coding; many experienced people who write code for a living either only use languages without collectors, or who have never even thought about the fact that memory needs collecting.